# Bluetooth logs from wireshark. Can anyone tell me what this is?

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark

Random mac address that changes every five-ten minutes or so. Sending out two different packets from the same address. What is this for?

No. Time Source Destination Protocol Length Info

```
9 0.821581 controller host HCI_EVT 42 Rcvd LE Meta (LE Advertising Report)

Frame 9: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface bluetooth-monitor, id 0

Bluetooth

Bluetooth Linux Monitor Transport
Bluetooth HCI Event - LE Meta
Event Code: LE Meta (0x3e)
Parameter Total Length: 40
Sub Event: LE Advertising Report (0x02)
Num Reports: 1
Event Type: Scannable Undirected Advertising (0x02)
Peer Address Type: Random Device Address (0x01)
BD_ADDR: 77:fd:98:85:c9:32 (77:fd:98:85:c9:32)
Data Length: 28

Advertising Data

16-bit Service Class UUIDs
Length: 3
Type: 16-bit Service Class UUIDs (0x03)
UUID 16: Google (0xfe9f)
Service Data - 16 bit UUID
Length: 23
Type: Service Data - 16 bit UUID (0x16)
UUID 16: Google (0xfe9f)
Service Data: 026f4c574c3751686a4f4c63000001759a6c74b2
RSSI: -75dBm
```

---

No. Time Source Destination Protocol Length Info

```
10 0.823598 controller host HCI_EVT 24 Rcvd LE Meta (LE Advertising Report)

Frame 10: 24 bytes on wire (192 bits), 24 bytes captured (192 bits) on 
interface bluetooth-monitor, id 0

Bluetooth

Bluetooth Linux Monitor Transport
Bluetooth HCI Event - LE Meta
Event Code: LE Meta (0x3e)
Parameter Total Length: 22
Sub Event: LE Advertising Report (0x02)
Num Reports: 1
Event Type: Scan Response (0x04)
Peer Address Type: Random Device Address (0x01)
BD_ADDR: 77:fd:98:85:c9:32 (77:fd:98:85:c9:32)
Data Length: 10

Advertising Data

Manufacturer Specific
Length: 9
Type: Manufacturer Specific (0xff)
Company ID: Google (0x00e0)
Data: 0a89fa5bf176
RSSI: -75dBm
```

Comment: Please could you consider reformatting this post to allow easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

This might be some kind of BLE beacon using a [random address for privacy](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/). Apart from being [registered](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/) to Google, there doesn't seem to be any other public information on its use